# Resize of child components Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, layout-manager

I want to know if I had a component,for example,button how to able it to resize if parent component is resized by user?

Comment: Resizing components such as buttons is almost always the wrong approach. Why do you want to resize the button? What does the rest of the frame contain?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your problem. Are you creating your GUI with the NetBeans drag-and-drop GUI creator? If so, are you having the container that holds the JButton use the default GroupLayout? If you want re-sizing, you'll want to use one of the other layouts, perhaps even a combination of layouts held by nested JPanels.

Comment: I put the button on the node cell of JGraph, when I resize node I have such problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is handled by the layout manager of the container. A button at the center of a BorderLayout will resize in all directions, for example.

Read the [Swing tutorial on layout managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).